MySQL Operator (2.1.3) - Deleting InnoDB Cluster Stuck
I deployed the mysql operator (2.1.3) on GKE via helm. While testing certain function I noticed that removing a innoDB cluster gets stuck on delete (I am using ArgoCD, but manual deployment tests showed the same outcome).
The innoDB cluster itself was created with kubectl manifest files at first but for a test install via helm showed the same issue. I can force the uninstallation by calling:
kubectl patch Pod mysql-db-0 -n mysql-db -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":[]}}' --type=merge
and
kubectl patch innoDBCluster mysql-db -n mysql-operator --type='json' -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/metadata/finalizers"}]'
but is this intended? I found a reference in a change log but I dont use ISTO
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql-operator/en/news-8-0-36-2.0.13.html
